# Currency Format Apache POI

Tags: java, apache-poi, stylesheet, libreoffice

I need to set format for BRL coin into my sheet. I'm using Apache POI for set currency style with code below:

```
XSSFCellStyle style = xssfWorkbook.createCellStyle();
style.setDataFormat(cf.getFormat("R$#,##0.00;\\R$-#,##0.00"));
```

But when i open my xlsx file into LibreOffice (i'm a linux user ), my  cells are not formatted. Checking the cell contains a quote *'* at beggin of cell value and when retired this quote, my cell value is formatted correctly. Prints of my sheet [after](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fxI39.png) and [before](https://i.stack.imgur.com/heJWq.png). Please any sugestions?

Edit: My method that create and setValue into cell (
passing as parameter the style above):

```
 public XSSFCell criarCelula(int indice, String conteudo, XSSFRow linha, XSSFCellStyle estilo) { 
   XSSFCell celula = linha.createCell(indice); 
   celula.setCellValue(conteudo); 
   celula.setCellStyle(estilo); 
   return celula; 
}
```

Comment: Please show the code which sets the cell value into cell `D7`. Seems as if you set string value instead of numeric value.

Comment: @AxelRichter i edited publication with code :)

Comment: `String conteudo` ... `celula.setCellValue(conteudo);`: This sets cell value as string (text). For numeric content `conteudo` also must be numeric. For example  `double conteudo` ... `celula.setCellValue(conteudo);`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it with sugestion of Axel Ritcher. Using my content into double type instead of string.

```
Double conteudo;
celula.setCellValue(conteudo);
```